# ScrollView Children and Accessibility

Tags: android, android-layout, android-scrollview, accessibility

I'm developing a Calendar Application and I want to make it accessible for visually impaired users. The CalendarScreen has a ScrollView that has one child, a DayViewGroup, which contain and lays out EventViews. For each EventView I set the contentDescription. Everything is created and added programatically.

When using TalkBack, the intent is for the user to be able to swipe through the EventViews of the *entire* day and hear the contentDescription. What I found is that the I'm only able to swipe through the EventViews that are currently being displayed by the ScrollView or ones that are slightly off screen.

My hypothesis is that the ScrollView is doing some optimizations and only rendering the relevant portion of the screen and either removing the EventViews that aren't being shown from the ViewHierarchy or making them invisible. Anyway, the result is that they are hidden from TalkBack and accessibility.

I'm thinking that I'll override the getAccessibilityNodeProvider in the DayViewGroup and have that provide the information there.

- An important feature of the CalendarScreen is that the user can click events and be taken to more information. I'm wondering if I'll be able to delegate TalkBack clicks to the VirtualNodeProvider?
- Is there a simpler solution? Perhaps turning off the optimization for the ScrollView or telling each EventView that it's important to accessibility?

Thanks!

Comment: This isn't really a `ScrollView` thing. List rows outside of the screen aren't rendered until the UI object is scrolled in. `RecyclerView` has the same behaviour except it "recycles" a view that was scrolled either up or down and replaces it in place of a new view coming into the screen. 

But also as TalkBack is concerned you can't focus a UI object that is not display.

Comment: I've a similar issue with NestedScrollview and talkback. Were you able to solve the issue @Ian